# Promise Fails to Resolve with TypeMoq Mock

Tags: typescript, promise, jasmine, typemoq

I've defined `MyService` as follows

```
export interface MyService {
    doStuff(): Promise<any>;
}
```

and `MyClass` that consumes `MyService` as

```
import {MyService} from "./my.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
export class MyClass {

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    useMyService(): Observable<boolean> {
        return Observable.create(obs => {
            this.myService.doStuff()
                .then((res: any) => {
                    console.log("Promise resolved!");
                    obs.next(true);
                })
                .catch((err: any) => {
                    console.log("Promise rejected!");
                    obs.error(false);
                })
        });
    };    
}
```

In addition, I have an interface `MyModel` defined as

```
export interface MyModel {
    someProperty: string;
}
```

Now I want to write a test such that I can mock `MyService` using TypeMoq. So I did the following

```
describe('MyClass', () => {

    it('useMyService returns true when myService returns true', (done) => {
        let mockModel = TypeMoq.Mock.ofType<MyModel>();
        mockModel.setup(x => x.someProperty).returns(() => "info");    

        let mockMyService = TypeMoq.Mock.ofType<MyService>();
        mockMyService.setup(x => x.doStuff()).returns(() => Promise.resolve(mockModel.object));

        let myClass = new MyClass(mockMyService.object);

        myClass.useMyService().subscribe(
            (result: boolean) => {
                expect(result).toBeTruthy();
                done();
            },
            (error: any) => {
                expect(error).toBeFalsy();
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

However, the `Promise.resolve(mockModel.object)` never seems to resolve when supplied with the TypeMoq mock as shown above, i.e., I don't get "Promise resolved!" (or "Promise rejected!") printed to the console and the jasmine test times out.

If I replace `Promise.resolve(mockModel.object)` with `Promise.resolve({ someProperty: 'info'})`, i.e.,

```
let mockMyService = TypeMoq.Mock.ofType<MyService>();
        mockMyService.setup(x => x.doStuff()).returns(() => Promise.resolve({ someProperty: 'info'}));
```

then the test works (I get "Promise resolved!" printed to the console). Why doesn't `Promise.resolve()` resolve when supplied with a TypeMoq mock?

Answer (score 5):

According to the author, this is "[a limitation of the underlying technology](https://github.com/florinn/typemoq/issues/66)" and apparently not something they intend to correct for in *TypeMoq*.

A workaround is offered that involves setting up `then()` method stubs on mocks that promises resolve to:

```js
mockModel.setup((x: any) => x.then).returns(() => undefined);
```

Whether this qualifies as a solution to the problem would seem to be a matter of opinion.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: This isn't a link to a solution, it's a statement of the library author's position on the problem, which I submit is useful on its own because it assures the asker that the difficulty they are encountering is not their own fault.  That said, I will attempt to expand on the answer.